# tkinter label text with utf-8 color codes issue

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am having problems with showing text with `utf-8` color codes in tkinter label.
My python script is receiving text lines with colored words with utf-8 color codes and I show them on a tk label. While the text is shown correctly the utf-8 color codes are not coloring the words but rather shown as simple codes.

Example:

[image: tk-window with label text]

As we can see the `GPU=60.10C` should have been colored with red, like below in shell window:

[image: shell window with same text but with colors]

How can I show the color in tk label without the need to change the received line and grepping the color code and add it to the label as text color or so?

Like:

```
root = Tk()
Label(root,text="red text",fg="red").grid(column=0,row=0)
```

The above solution would add more complexity and more implementation then anticipated!

Comment: Does this  link help? https://python-tricks.com/text-in-tkinter/

Answer (score 1):

To complete Bryan Oakley's answer here is how you can parse the string and apply the color using tags in a `Text` widget:

1. Configure tags for the color / formatting codes you want with

   ```
   text.tag_configure(<tag name>, **options)
   ```

   The list of tag options is available for instance [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-methods.html).
2. Create a dictionary associating each color code with the corresponding tag
3. Insert the string in the `Text` widget without the color codes. You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to remove the color codes:

   ```
   re.sub(r"\x1b\[((\d+;)*\d+)m", "", <string>)
   ```
4. Using the same regular expression, parse you string with to find the color codes and apply the tags. There are a couple of tricky parts here:

   - The color code positions do not match the text index because the codes have been removed from the text in the widget, so you need to keep track of the cumulated offset for each line.
   - You need to wait until you find a "closing" code (e.g. color change, or `\x1b[0m`) to be able to add the tag with `text.tag_add(<tag name>, <start>, <stop>)` and therefore you need to keep track of the opened tags.

Code example, not exhaustive (e.g. bold and italic at the same time not suported) but covers the basics:

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

# dictionaries to replace formatting code with tags
ansi_font_format = {1: 'bold', 3: 'italic', 4: 'underline', 9: 'overstrike'}
ansi_font_reset = {21: 'bold', 23: 'italic', 24: 'underline', 29: 'overstrike'}

# tag configuration
text.tag_configure('bold', font=('', 9, 'bold'))
text.tag_configure('italic', font=('', 9, 'italic'))
text.tag_configure('underline', underline=True)
text.tag_configure('overstrike', overstrike=True)

# dictionaries to replace color code with tags
ansi_color_fg = {39: 'foreground default'}
ansi_color_bg = {49: 'background default'}

text.tag_configure('foreground default', foreground=text["fg"])
text.tag_configure('background default', background=text["bg"])

ansi_colors_dark = ['black', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'royal blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'light gray']
ansi_colors_light = ['dark gray', 'tomato', 'light green', 'light goldenrod', 'light blue', 'pink', 'light cyan', 'white']

for i, (col_dark, col_light) in enumerate(zip(ansi_colors_dark, ansi_colors_light)):
    ansi_color_fg[30 + i] = 'foreground ' + col_dark
    ansi_color_fg[90 + i] = 'foreground ' + col_light
    ansi_color_bg[40 + i] = 'background ' + col_dark
    ansi_color_bg[100 + i] = 'background ' + col_light
    # tag configuration
    text.tag_configure('foreground ' + col_dark, foreground=col_dark)
    text.tag_configure('background ' + col_dark, background=col_dark)
    text.tag_configure('foreground ' + col_light, foreground=col_light)
    text.tag_configure('background ' + col_light, background=col_light)

# regular expressionto find ansi codes in string
ansi_regexp = re.compile(r"\x1b\[((\d+;)*\d+)m")

def insert_ansi(txt, index="insert"):
    first_line, first_char = map(int, str(text.index(index)).split("."))
    if index == "end":
        first_line -= 1

    lines = txt.splitlines()
    if not lines:
        return
    # insert text without ansi codes
    text.insert(index, ansi_regexp.sub('', txt))
    # find all ansi codes in txt and apply corresponding tags
    opened_tags = {}  # we need to keep track of the opened tags to be able to do
                      # text.tag_add(tag, start, end) when we reach a "closing" ansi code

    def apply_formatting(code, code_index):
        if code == 0:  # reset all by closing all opened tag
            for tag, start in opened_tags.items():
                text.tag_add(tag, start, code_index)
            opened_tags.clear()
        elif code in ansi_font_format:  # open font formatting tag
            tag = ansi_font_format[code]
            opened_tags[tag] = code_index
        elif code in ansi_font_reset:   # close font formatting tag
            tag = ansi_font_reset[code]
            if tag in opened_tags:
                text.tag_add(tag, opened_tags[tag], code_index)
                opened_tags.remove(tag)
        elif code in ansi_color_fg:    # open foreground color tag (and close previously opened one if any)
            for tag in tuple(opened_tags):
                if tag.startswith('foreground'):
                    text.tag_add(tag, opened_tags[tag], code_index)
                    opened_tags.remove(tag)
            opened_tags[ansi_color_fg[code]] = code_index
        elif code in ansi_color_bg:    # open background color tag (and close previously opened one if any)
            for tag in tuple(opened_tags):
                if tag.startswith('background'):
                    text.tag_add(tag, opened_tags[tag], code_index)
                    opened_tags.remove(tag)
            opened_tags[ansi_color_bg[code]] = code_index

    def find_ansi(line_txt, line_nb, char_offset):
        delta = -char_offset  # difference between the character position in the original line and in the text widget
                              # (initial offset due to insertion position if first line + extra offset due to deletion of ansi codes)
        for match in ansi_regexp.finditer(line_txt):
            codes = [int(c) for c in match.groups()[0].split(';')]
            start, end = match.span()
            for code in codes:
                apply_formatting(code, "{}.{}".format(line_nb, start - delta))
            delta += end - start  # take into account offste due to deletion of ansi code

    find_ansi(lines[0], first_line, first_char) # first line, with initial offset due to insertion position
    for line_nb, line in enumerate(lines[1:], first_line + 1):
        find_ansi(line, line_nb, 0)   # next lines, no offset
    # close still opened tag
    for tag, start in opened_tags.items():
        text.tag_add(tag, start, "end")


# example for the kind of output you can get with "ls --color"
output = 'file.pdf\nfile.txt\n\x1b[0m\x1b[01;34mfolder\x1b[0m\n\x1b[01;32mscript.py\x1b[0m\ntest\n'
insert_ansi(output, "end")
```

Example with colored output from the `ls --color` command in Linux:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter widgets don't support color codes embedded in the text. Further, the `Label` widget can only have a single foreground color and a single background color.

If you want multiple colors, your only option is to use a `Text` or `Canvas` widget, parsing the string, and applying the colors in an appropriate manner.