# Tkinter coloring specific words in buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

I have this function that prints words in specific colors and you can actually use this with any string.

```
def colored_string(color, text):
    """Returns the given text with the specified color code."""
    return f"{color}{text}\x1b[0m"

text = "This text is black but this is a red dot" + colored_string("\x1b[31m", chr(9673))
print(text)
```

However if I try to use it in tkinter, not only the color doesn't appear, but it displays the color code as well.

```
import tkinter as tk

def colored_string(color, text):
    """Returns the given text with the specified color code."""
    return f"{color}{text}\x1b[0m"

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x100")

button = tk.Button(root, text = "This text is black but this is a red dot" + colored_string("\x1b[31m", chr(9673)), command=lambda: label.pack(pady=10))
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to have the string appearing the same way as in the print statement above?

Comment: `tkinter` does not support ANSI color escape code.

Comment: @acw1668 is there a workaround?

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279937/tkinter-label-text-with-utf-8-color-codes-issue) help.

Comment: line 10, in <lambda>
    button = tk.Button(root, text = "This text is black but this is a red dot" + colored_string("\x1b[31m", chr(9673)), command=lambda: label.pack(pady=10))
                                                                                                                                        ^^^^^
NameError: name 'label' is not defined

Comment: @Warehouse_Worker. Do you want text as black and period for red? Correct me as right?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Tkinter doesn't support ANSI escape codes. There is no way to colorize only parts of a string in tkinter labels or buttons. The only options for displaying strings in multiple colors is to use a `Text` widget or a `Canvas` widget.